# OSX - How can I see the TID of all threads from my process?

Tags: macos, pthreads, pid

On Linux `ps -eLf | grep my-process-name` gives a list of the threads within my process along with the TID of each thread.

On OSX `ps -M pid` gives me the list of the threads but does not show the TID of each thread.

How can I see thread TIDs under a single process from the command line?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't see the TIDs with the `ps` on Mac OS as you can experience while listing all the possible column options with `ps L`.

Anyway, if you dont mind exploring the threads as a root, you can use [`dtruss`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dtruss.1m.html), which is primarily for processing syscall details, but it will at least show you the TIDs in the PID/**LWPID** (PID/**THRD**) column.

```
sudo dtruss -ap pid
```

Comment: the output of dtruss doesn't show the pthread thread id, it shows a OSX-specific pointer id.   converting between them is challenging

Answer (score 3):

Well, although I realize it may be considered sacrilegious to some, cross platform Powershell is now available for macOS, and it's pretty trivial to see thread ids with it.  This will work:

```
Get-Process -Id 1234 | Select-Object Threads
```

It will spit back an object for each applicable thread that contains about 10 properties. One of them is 'Id'. You could also do:

```
gps -Id 1234 | select -Expand Threads | select -Expand Id
```

If you wanted to shorten the command up, and just get back the Ids.