# Visualizing ruby threads with htop command

Tags: ruby, multithreading, htop

I am experimenting with multithreading in ruby. I ran this piece of code that runs 3 threads concurrently (`ruby threads.rb` in my terminal):

```
arr = []
arr.push(Thread.new do
  1000000.times do |i|
    puts "thread 1"
  end
end)
arr.push(Thread.new do
  1000000.times do |i|
    puts "thread 2"
  end
end)

arr.push(Thread.new do
  1000000.times do |i|
    puts "thread 3"
  end
end)

arr.each {|t| t.join}
```

I am now running `htop` in tree view in my terminal to see if I can actually see the 3 different threads :

[image]

I think the process threads.rb is the line right under the highlighted one, but I cant see my three launched threads as branches of the threads.rb process..
Do ruby threads have nothing to do with threads and processes displayed with htop ? Is there a way to visualize the different ruby threads running inside my threads.rb process.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your Ruby interpreter. MRI should allocate a native thread for each Ruby thread. I've ran your script and I can see threads in `htop` (there's more than 3 threads, but that must be something the interpreter does):

[image: htop]

Try setting a filter in `htop` (hit `F4` and type `ruby` as a filter string).

EDIT: I've tested on Debian. `htop` on MacOS apparently doesn't show threads.

Comment: What OS and Ruby interpreter are you running?  I'm on MacOS 10.14.3 and tested on MRI and don't see native threads.

Comment: nope only see one ruby threads.rb process which seem to be a child from atom. Im running on MRI too with macos 10.14.4

Comment: Oh, OK -- I'm on Debian. Seems like `htop` doesn't show threads on OSX: https://github.com/hishamhm/htop/issues/552 -- there's a PR open, but it's not merged. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28047653/osx-how-can-i-see-the-tid-of-all-threads-from-my-process, HTH.